Multiple City Codes in the Order File
I have an order file that has origin_city & destination_city fileds. Both are codes that reference records in the city file. I am trying to create a query that will select the city_name for both of the city codes.
I have tried left Outer Join of the Order File to the City file on the origin_city = city_code and a separate join for the destination_city.  I'm only able to get the first city_name to come back from the city_file.

Please add your query to the question.

I suggest you use LEFT JOIN in case a bad city code is used
SELECT o.*, 
       oc.City_Name as OriginCityName,
       dc.City_Name as DestinationCityName
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN City oc ON o.origin_City = oc.City_Code
LEFT JOIN City dc ON o.destination_city = dc.City_Code

fiddle



OrderId
origin_city
destination_city
OriginCityName
DestinationCityName




1
ny
bos
NewYork
Boston


2
alb
sf
Albany
NULL


3
mtl
la
Montreal
Los Angles


4
atl
sea
Atlanta
Seattle




This worked.  Thanks for your help!

This will look something like:
SELECT order.order_number, 
   order.origin_city, 
   origin.city_name, 
   order.destination_city, 
   destination.name
FROM order
   INNER JOIN city as origin
      ON order.origin_city = origin.city_code
   INNER JOIN city as destinition
      ON order.destination_city = destination.city_code

As you supsected, we join twice to the same table/file. In each join we alias that table/file with origin or destination and we join on either the origin_city or destiniation_city column

This worked.  Thanks for your help!
